# how to access the UL “id',”name" etc. of Loaded URL within a Div using JQuery.Load to set JQuery Treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery

## sample.html Code

```
<ul id="browser" class="filetree">
   <li><span class="folder">Folder 1</span>
        <ul>
            <li><span class="file">Item 1.1</span></li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

## Main Page Code

```
<div id="LtrLeftContent">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#LtrLeftContent').load('sample.html');
   </script>                    
</div>
```

Page Loaded successfully. But **unable to populate** Jquery Treeview using bellow code within **Main Page**

**Process 1:**

```
$("div#LtrLeftContent").contents().find("ul#browser").treeview();
```

**Process 2:**

```
$("div#LtrLeftContent").ready(function () {
    $("ul#browser.filetree").treeview();
});
```

**Process 3:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul#browser").treeview();
});
```

**Process 4:**

```
$("#LtrLeftContent").html().find("#browser").treeview();
```

But if I put bellow code into "**sample.html**". the code populate the Treeview successfully

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#browser").treeview();
});
```

How to set treeview into **Main Page** in order to populate JQuery treeview ?

**Note:** I don't want put Javascript into "**Sample.html**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to wait with populating the treeview for sample.html to load (see [docs for load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)):

```
$('#LtrLeftContent').load('sample.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
    $("#browser").treeview();
});
```